# Python - Attempting to print an integer in reverse

Tags: python

For example I want the input 234 to print out 432. I thought I had it nailed down, but for whatever reason I always get a runtime error. I'm alright with Java, but Python is new to me and any help would be much appreciated.

```
def reverseDigits(n):
    reverse = n % 10
    str(reverse)
    n = n // 10
    while n > 0:
        temp = n % 10
        str(temp)
        reverse = str(reverse) + str(temp)
        temp = int(temp)
        n // 10
    return reverse

def main():
    n = eval(input("Enter a integer: "))
    print("The reverse of the digits of ", n, "is", reverseDigits(n))

main()
```

Comment: Note that `str(x)` doesn't modify `x`; it only evaluates `str(x)` and discards the value. Those lines are doing nothing in your code.

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how Python handles data types. `str(reverse)` does not declare `reverse` as a string, nor does it modify `reverse` in any way. All it does is return the string representation of `reverse`.

Comment: @coldspeed it doesnt look like issue with `str` it is a logic issue

Answer (score 5):

You can just use list slicing:

```
n = int(input("Enter a integer: "))
new_integer = int(str(n)[::-1])
```

note that use of `eval` is highly discouraged as it leaves your system susceptible to code injection.

Comment: A sentence of explanation and you've got 4 votes... well done ;)

Answer (score 0):

change the line inside the while loop [error is because it goes into infinite loop]

```
 n // 10
```

to

```
 n = n // 10
```